# iOS developer program for open source community?

Tags: ios

I googled for a while but can't get anything about ios developer program for open source community. As you may see, we currently have an iOS project that wants to publish to Apple's app store. But sadly, because we are just a group of people on the internet and is not a company, we can't get enterprise account for this case.

But because we don't want to publish an app on half of specific person, we are thinking is there any other way to get a different account for this case ? or can we register with personal account but change that to the team's name ?

I am sure that there must be some people around the internet having the same problems like us and please share your ideas or any possible way to achieve this.

THank :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, Apple does not provide an account type for *a group of people* who are not an organization nor a company and don't have a team lead, either. You need to elect someone from that group of people as the lead/manager or whatever you name it, and then let that person get the account with their credits, **but** use a different *seller* name that would match your group of people, rather than an individual person's name. But in a business world, there's no point of having a group of people working together aimlessly without having a registered company.

**Also, this is an off-topic question for S.O. since it has nothing to do with your code. For general questions like this, refer to chat rooms or forums.**